# Is mapWithState/updateStateByKey cached?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Let's assume, I have an application

1. Create a new stream from kafka
2. Do some transformations
3. Use `mapWithState`/`updateStateByKey` to save state.
4. Do some more transformation on the stream from state.
5. Do some action1 and action2.

Note: I have not used any cache as of yet.

My question is,

- Will the transformation at step 2 be performed twice (once for action1 and action2 each)? For me, it seems to be executing only once!!!
- `mapWithState`/`updateStateByKey` return `dStream`, but does it do some caching/storing automatically?
- Is there a guaranty, the transformations before `mapWithState`/`updateStateByKey` are applied only once and not re-computed? I mean, If the state still contains data acquired 30 days before, will it re-compute if the pre-computed result not found?

Answer (score 1):

> Will the transformation at step 2 be performed twice (once for action1
>   and action2 each)? For me, it seems to be executing only once

This really depends on what transformations we're talking about. If you have two branches of a graph, each doing some computation in parallel, it should work.

> mapWithState/updateStateByKey return dStream, but does it do some
>   caching/storing automatically?

The whole point of those transformations is to keep state between iterations, and that's what they do. `mapWithState` has an explicit `State[S]` object which you add/update/delete yourself.

> Is there a guaranty, the transformations before
>   mapWithState/updateStateByKey are applied only once and not
>   re-computed? I mean, If the state still contains data acquired 30 days
>   before, will it re-compute if the pre-computed result not found

All transformations other than `mapWithState` and `updateStateByKey` are stateless. If an `RDD` as a whole is missing a piece of necessary data, it can request re-compute that part of the `RDD` which is missing. If that's what you mean.